# Is it possible to apply slicing to django function on template?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I´m trying to make a whatsapp button but I´m having problems with the trailing slash at the end on the href.  Whatsapp renders wrongly with the trailing slash.

I´m using wagtail and puput. **I´d like to do it on template only** because wagtail and puput are addons on divio. If I install them separatedly, I would have to remake my website, so I can´t change models.py.

I´m using `{% canonical_url entry %}` for the href. What I´d like to have would be something like `{% canonical_url|slice:":-1" entry %}`

They provide `full_url` placeholder, but it doesn´t add date to link. It gives *foo.com/slug* instead of *foo.com/2017/09/01/slug* so everything gets rendered wrong too.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: For the first part of the question, can you update the question with what a valid url should look like and what you have showing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to use `{% canonical_url entry as url %}` to get the desired URL as the variable `url`, rather than outputting it directly from the tag. After that, you can perform the slicing on the variable using `{{ url|slice:":-1" }}`.

Comment: I get this error: 

TemplateSyntaxError at /

'canonical_url' received too many positional arguments

Comment: I discovered I´m using django 1.8. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, that'll be it. `canonical_url` is [implemented in puput as a `simple_tag`](https://github.com/APSL/puput/commit/9d7d783362f234eb3aa6f918e2fa094553e9364f), and the ability to use `as [variable]` on a simple_tag was only introduced in Django 1.9.

Comment: I´m making updates. I think you got it! after I finnish it I´l confirm as correct answer. Thanks a lot for everyone for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly such a thing: [the slice builtin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice).

The example in the documentation is this:

```
{{ some_list|slice:":2" }}
```

But as a string is also a list of chars in Python it should work fine with a string as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I don't think he tested his example here judging by his words "I´d like to have would be something like "

Comment: I tried it, but it is a function called 'canonical_url'.  it is not a list. I also have to pass the argument 'entry'

Comment: I also thought of something like {% canonical_url entry as placeholder %} but it didn´tt work, as it didn´t something like {% with canonical url entry as placeholder %}